# JSON Formatting : How to add mail link when multiple user

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I would like to add the mail icon in front of multiple users. I followed the tutorials but they just explain how to put the icon when there is only one user. What I have:

[image: What I have]

What I would like to have:

[image: What I would like to have]

When I use the script suggested by the documentation, it will only display the icon for the first user, but not on subsequent users. Moreover, their names disappear.

Does anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Use below JSON for your requirements:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
              },
              "txtContent": "[$personIterator.title]"
            },
            {
              "elmType": "a",
              "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                  "operator": "+",
                  "operands": [
                    "mailto:",
                    "[$personIterator.email]",
                    "?subject=Task status&body=Hey, how is your task coming along?.\r\n---\r\n",
                    "[$personIterator.title]",
                    "\r\nClick this link for more info. http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ConferencePrep/Tasks/Prep/DispForm.aspx?ID=",
                    "[$ID]"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

You can change color or other CSS properties as per your requirements.

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Hello, thank you but it still doesn't work for me. I work on Sharepoint server 2019

Comment: Ah, SP 2019 uses `https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json` schema which does not support `forEach`.

Comment: is there an alternative ?

Comment: I am not sure about it in SP 2019 as I don't have environment to test this. [@theChrisKent](https://twitter.com/theChrisKent) might know alternative solution for this if any.

Comment: Could it be because Sharepoint server 2019 uses Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and not Excel-style like Sharepoint Online for JSON formatting?
I already had a lot of problem with this, and it's hard for me to rewrite the code in ATS..